# VerifyError: class net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter overrides final method visit

Tags: java, testing, junit

I ran into this error when running unit tests.

I use intellij and EasyMock 3.0 and cglib (2.2) and Objenesis (1.2).

Here is my test:

```
public void testGetContentOk() throws Exception {
    EasyMock.expect(mockConnectionFactory.getData()).andReturn(mockInputStream);
    EasyMock.expect(mockInputStream.read()).andReturn(new Integer( (byte)'I'));
    EasyMock.expect(mockInputStream.read()).andReturn(-1);
    mockInputStream.close();
    EasyMock.replay(mockConnectionFactory);
    EasyMock.replay(mockInputStream);
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    String result = webClient.getContent(mockConnectionFactory);
    Assert.assertEquals("I", result);
}
```

Does anyone know why this happens?

I'm curious about this since I already use the right version at least I think so. I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Check libraries dependencies of your project. For example if your project uses asm.jar make sure that it is in correct version for you cglib. As far as I know asm 3.3 works with cglib 2.2 fine but later version will clash.

Answer (score 0):

I just get some similar problem.try to get the dependency tree.
If you can find there's some lib depends on asm 4.0. And as asm 4.0 cann't work well with cglib 2.2. That may be the reason.

With my own case, I use maven for project so that `mvn dependency:tree`  to get the dependency tree. And I found something like this:

> [INFO] |  |  |  - com.esotericsoftware.kryo:kryo:jar:2.21:compile
>
> [INFO] |  |  |     +- com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm:reflectasm:jar:shaded:1.07:compile
>
> [INFO] |  |  |     |  - org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:4.0:compile

I change asm to 3.1 and it works.And EasyMock need to use some thing like asm, it will depend on it.
May that help.